# How to upgrade JabRef correctly?

Tags: upgrade

[The question was asked on TeX.SE with no answer and considered off-topic, so here I am asking again]

I already have an old version of JabRef that came along with

```
sudo apt install jabref
```

JabRef has recently introduced many attractive features so I obviously want to upgrade to the latest.

I know I can use the .jar file directly, but I want not to disturb the existing elaborate installation, rather just want to modify itself to the latest.

> Could someone suggest instructions to build on top of "sudo apt install" to upgrade existing JabRef to the latest version?

For such an awesome project of JabRef, the installation page at https://help.jabref.org/en/Installation looks rather useless. The page only talks about the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) rather than the actual installation. (The JRE is of course necessary, but it is just one pre-requisite part!)

Comment: You cannot build on top of the Debian package installation - you'll have to either compile from source *after* removing the older `jabref`, *or* find a PPA with a newer version, *or* attempt to build the package with the newer `jabref` source code.  None of these options are trivial, however.